# Is asking for "which tool does X" ok?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I came across [What java obsfuscator is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45612046/what-java-obsfuscator-is-thatcode-is-full-of-up-and-lowercase-is). The user shows some obviously obfuscated code and asks which tool does this kind of obfuscation.

So - he is not asking to recommend a tool but to *determine* the tool that (probably) creates certain output.

Now I am wondering what the correct "response" is - closing it as "asking for recommendation for offsite resource?"

And as the question already vanished:

[image: question-screenshot]

Comment: It is not even clear that there will be one definite answer. Who knows how many obfuscators will use this patterns?

Comment: *"Questions asking us to [...] find a [...] tool [...] are off-topic for Stack Overflow"* could be applied to that question.

Comment: @Floern Yes. But on the other hand. That reads like Fox News quoting a Trump email. Meaning: if those things replaced with  [...] would not matter - then why isn't the "close" reason written like that?!

Comment: I just [...]'ed out the non-matching options in the list. It's one specific interpretation of the close reason. "recommend or find" -> "find"; "book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource" -> "tool"

Comment: The question itself may or may not match the criteria to close it as it is written (I mean there is a chance that there is only one tool that does this...), but it seems a rather useless question with no sign of any research having been done, not likely to help anyone else. I'd definitely downvote it.

Comment: @Floern May I play devil's advocate for a moment? The close reason toes not forbid _identification_ of tools . While this particular question is not a good fit for SO, some of our sister sites allow for identification questions.

Comment: [Related (obviously not duplicate)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354707/trying-to-understand-why-my-direct-answer-was-converted-to-a-comment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By reading the close reason one more time

> Questions asking us to recommend **or *find*** a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

You will see, your first instinct was correct. You can read it as *recommend a tool* **or** find a tool. The last one seems pretty acurate for this case.

That *X* is a obuscated source code doesn't matter. It can also be, Which tool create this type of usercontrol *[Some Random Image]*, and the close reason would be more clearly ;)

On the other site, we have a question like this:

[What does the custom function(p,a,c,k,e,d) used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21423397/what-does-the-custom-functionp-a-c-k-e-d-used-for)

But here, the motivation behind the question is not finding a tool. It is finding a explaination what this ugly thing is.

That said, sometimes you should make an exception. But most of times, you can close it.

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't demonstrate minimal searching efforts. A simple Google query of "obfuscate tool Java" will lead to the closed Stack Overflow question:

[Best Java obfuscator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537568/best-java-obfuscator)

OP can improve his question by listing the technologies he came across, and by trying to better describe what he's trying to exactly achieve. I think that the question can be rewritten in such a way that it won't be necessarily closed. But IMO the question as-is, should be closed.